# Is the Rick Astley chiptune available to download anywhere?

Tags: discussion, unikong

In Unikong, if you enter the Konami code, instead of the normal in-game music you get to listen to a chiptune version of Rick Astley's hit song, "Never Gonna Give You Up".

Is there a place where we can download this song or will StackExchange make it publicly available?

Comment: Who or what is Unikong?

Comment: gaming.stackexchange.com

Comment: I don't think they're ever gonna give it up, sorry to let you down.

Comment: @scriptHero And here I was, thinking that SE wouldn't turn around and desert me :(

Comment: We didn't make it, but I will happily direct you to the person who did when I'm back at my desktop at home.

Comment: I can't seem to trigger it :(

Comment: The UniKong version is at http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/unikong/game-over-music.mp3

Comment: @ɥʇǝS After keying the Konami code, press ENTER.

Comment: @Loovjo File has been removed?!

Comment: @scriptHero yes, by SE team. (http://cdn.sstatic.net/ is owned by SE.)

Comment: Why am I reading this question’s title as “Is Rick Astley able to downvote anywhere?”?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, we didn't make this particular rendition of the timeless classic.

The credit (also listed in the game itself) belongs to [Toast024](http://youtube.com/user/Toast024) on Youtube. We've edited the track to create a version better suited to looping indefinitely. The original was unfortunately taken down by YouTube.

Comment: Well the video got taken down by YouTube...

Comment: @scriptHero in those cases feel free to edit out the broken link.

Answer (score 5):

The link provided by Loovjo has been saved by Internet Archive Wayback Machine:

http://web.archive.org/web/20160403053628/http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/unikong/game-over-music.mp3